# Are mersenne numbers with prime exponent cube free?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, open-problem

It is not known if mersenne numbers with prime exponent are square free. It is an open problem in number theory.
Some limitations on the divisors are discussed in:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149511/squarefree-parts-of-mersenne-numbers

Do we know if a mersenne numbers with prime exponent are cube free?

Comment: If $q$ and $p$ are primes, then $q^2|2^p-1$ implies that $q$ is a Wieferich-prime different from the known Wieferich-primes. $q$ must be larger than $10^{17}$, since no further Wieferich-prime below this mark exists. So $q^3|2^p-1$ would be surprising, considering that it is widely believed that already $q^2|2^p-1$ is impossible. Nevertheless, my guess is that the described problem is open as well.

Comment: @Peter How does it follow from $q^2\mid 2^p-1$ that $q$ is Wieferish?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms No, the definition entails $q^2\mid 2^{q-1}-1$, not $2^p-1$ for some other prime $p$.

Comment: @Wojowu - yes, sorry I've noticed that mess and deleted my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a full answer, but a proof that $2^p\equiv 1\mod q^2$ with primes $p,q$ implies that $q$ is a Wieferich prime.

Define $m=ord_2(q^2)$ , in other words, $m$ is the smallest positive integer with $$2^m\equiv 1\mod q^2$$

Because of $$2^p\equiv 1\mod q^2$$ the order must be $1$ or $p$. $1$ can be ruled out because of $2\ne 1\mod q^2$ , hence the order must be $p$.

Euler's theorem states $$2^{q(q-1)}\equiv1\mod q^2$$ hence $p|q(q-1)$.

$p|q$ would imply $p=q$ , but $2^q\equiv 2\ne 1\mod q$ , hence $2^q\ne 1\mod q^2$. Hence $p$ must divide $q-1$ implying $$2^{q-1}\equiv 1\mod q^2$$

Hence $q$ is a Wieferich-prime.

Comment: Analogue, it can be proven that $q^3|2^p-1$ implies $$2^{q-1}\equiv1\mod q^3$$

Comment: Because there are $q$ with higher exponents for other bases than $q=2$ it is not impossible, that "Wieferich"-primes  with higher exponents exist too. I've done some heuristics on this a couple of years ago in the hope to find patterns to improve statistically founded expectations, perhaps you like that essay at http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquotients.pdf

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Does that mean that the question is an open problem ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. A common keyword is *"high fermatquotient"*

Comment: Great answer, @Peter with a focus on pedagogy!  +1!  For the first time, I am not afraid to apply the concept of order to future mathematical arguments.  Thank you for teaching me this concept, through this answer.  =)